# Android custom input method: layout_alignParentBottom causes input area to fill most of screen

Tags: android, android-input-method

I created a custom input method that changes layouts dynamically. I want to align the last view to the bottom of the input area. I set the layout_alignParentBottom property for the last view, but then the input area expands to fill almost the entire screen, as seen here.

## Without layout_alignParentBottom set

[image: Login button does not have layout_alignParentBottom set]

## With layout_alignParentBottom set

[image: Login button has layout_AlignParentBottom set]

I do have an android:windowBackground style set, but even without it, it does the same thing. I inflate my XML layout in my custom InputMethodService class in onCreateInputView(), and I don't adjust any layout settings in the onFinishInflate() method of MyClass. Here is my code. Any ideas?

## my_class_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.package.MyClass xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/login" />

</com.package.MyClass>
```

## MyClass.java

```
package com.package;

<imports>

public class MyClass extends RelativeLayout {
private final MyClassInputMethodService mInputMethodServiceContext;
private Button mLoginButton;

public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mInputMethodServiceContext = (MyClassInputMethodService)context;
}

public MyClass( MyClassInputMethodService context ) {
    super(context);
    mInputMethodServiceContext = (MyClassInputMethodService)context;
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {

    // Login button
    mLoginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
}
```

## MyClassInputMethodService.java

```
package com.package;

<imports> 

public class MyClassInputMethodService extends InputMethodService {

private static final String TAG = MyClassInputMethodService.class.getSimpleName();

private static MyClassInputMethodService mContext;
private View mInputView;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

// Set Theme
setTheme(UserManagement.getCurrentUser().getTheme().getResourceId());
super.onCreate();
mContext = this;
}

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
     mInputView = (MyClassLogin) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fast_fill_login, null);
    return mInputView;
}

}
```

## EDIT

I tried a smaller-sized image for the windowBackground drawable, and it did make the default input method area smaller.

```
<style name="Theme.Blue" >
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_blue</item>
</style>
```

So that leads me to another possibility. Do I have to use the smallest possible background image size that would fit the least number of views that will be shown, or can I make the windowBackground drawable dynamic, so it will only use as much height as the input method views use?

Comment: can u post com.package.MyClass code?

Comment: I added the related classes with the barebones code and ensured the problem still exists.

Comment: Try setting a fixed height for MyClass View android:layout_height = "100dp"

Comment: I try to avoid hard-coded dimensions, but perhaps it's necessary in this situation?

Comment: Or create smaller background image